# The action Remove contact from group not working in Civirules

Tags: civirules

I'm using CiviCRM 4.7.23 version.Using civirules, For the trigger-"Contact of any type is restored" , Action -"Remove contact from group" .If any contact is restored from trash, it should be removed from the group.This is not working for me. The contact is not removed from the group.
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Updating the latest version of CiviRules will fix this. This bug has been fixed two weeks ago.

Comment: I'm using latest Civirules v1.23 but it doesn't work.

Comment: Ehm, could you verify whether another action does work with the trigger? It might be that the trigger restore from trash doesn't really work.

Comment: I have also experienced this issue when using the option contact participant status has changed

Comment: We are using CiviCRM 5.6.1, and CiviRules 2.4, but I see now that the project is no longer available on gitub, has it been scrapped???

Comment: Ignore that last bit, the info displayed on the extension page is out of date, the current repo is here: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civirules